# Opencart show all products in search page

Tags: php, opencart

In opencart 2.1.0.2, I am trying to display in search page all products instead of the configuration limit.

In catalog/controller/product/search.php

there is the following code in 375 line:

```
$data['limits'] = array();

        $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get('config_product_limit'), 25, 50, 100));

        sort($limits);

        foreach($limits as $value) {
            $data['limits'][] = array(
                'text'  => $value,
                'value' => $value,
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&limit=' . $value)
            );
        }
```

Also in around 62 line there is:

```
        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
        $limit = (int)$this->request->get['limit'];
    } else {
        $limit = $this->config->get('config_product_limit');
    }
```

I tried to set

```
 $limit = 9999;
```

Also to replace

```
    25, 50, 100 with 9999
```

but no luck.

What I am trying to accomplish is in the search result page of opencart 2 to get all products (=9999) in order to remove pagination but also keep the other pages product limit per page.

Any ideas? pointers?

thank you!

Comment: what happened when you made those changes?

Comment: nothing, and I cleared cache and vqmod cache. I also tried to set in 426 line $pagination->limit = 9999; Instead of $pagination->limit = $limit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all products in product search, you need to modify params of
`$filter_data`.

In catalog/controller/product/search.php

remove `order`, `start` & `limit` from `$filter_data`.

```
$filter_data = array(
    'filter_name'         => $search,
    'filter_tag'          => $tag,
    'filter_description'  => $description,
    'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
    'filter_sub_category' => $sub_category,
    'sort'                => $sort
);
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: that did the trick, it removed all formating because of my theme, but it did the trick